# Primefaces Spinner Modified Step Factor

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spinner

I'm trying to modify the step factor of the spinner a little bit. My intention is stepping to exact numbers.
So for example my step factor is 0.25 and my number I wrote into the spinner is 0.8 it will jump forward to 1.05 and backward to 0.55. But my intention is stepping to exact factors of the step factor. So in this case it should jump to 0.75 and 1.

This is the code for the calendar I got right now:

```
<prime:spinner id="inputHoursMonday"
value="#{attendance.value}" size="5"
max="#{bean.hoursMaxValue}" stepFactor="0.25"
min="0"
disabled="#{attendance.hoursBookedForAttendance}"/>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the user allowed to save values which do not fit to the step factor e.q. 0.8?

Comment: No it is not allowed to. But in this case I just want to adjust the spinner and not the saving progress.

Comment: Then make the spinner `readonly="true"` and provide an appropriate initial value.

Comment: No that is not the problem. The user can adjust the value through the spinner. But when he is adjusting the spinner shall jump in 0.25 rhythms. Look above for my intention.

Comment: Then download the javascript source for the spinner and adapt it there... Should not be too difficult

Comment: It is already adapted. The user can already adjust the spinner but not as I want to.

Comment: I don't understand what's your plan. Why only adjust the spinner if the user isn't allowed to save values like 0.8? Then the user could still save such values if he uses the normal input. So why not implement a valueChangeListener or Converter which rounds each value which is typed in to the next step factor?

Comment: If the user can adjust it but not as you want to, it is **not** adapted... Your question or rather the actual current problem is now sort of unclear for me

Comment: that is my actual problem! I need something which rounds my number. That is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Then download the javascript source for the spinner and adapt it there... Should not be too difficult: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+rouding+number

Comment: Maybe my explanation is not the best so I try to describe it as best as I can again:

I got a spinner with a stepFactor of 0.25.
Now for example the spinner has the number 0.5. Through the up arrow it turns into 0.75 and through the down arrow in 0.25.

But now the spinner has the number 0.4. Through the up arrow it turns into 0.65 and through the down arrow in 0.15.

My intention is actually to turn the number from 0.4 to 0.5 and 0.25.

Comment: Easiest solution is to prevent the spinner to get a value of 0.4 since it seems 0.4 is not a value you want at all (e.g. what if the user does not change it at all?. 2 solutions: Round it off before passing it to the spinner or when initially storing the 0.4, already round it off to 0.5... Most easy, clear and explicit thing to do

Answer (score 0):

As I said there are a few options, I expect the value is a double in my answer. If you have more than one spinner I'd recommened to use a converter, because you can just add it to every spinner.

**Note:** You only need to add p:ajax if you want to see the correct value immediately after the spinner got changed. If it's okay to wait until the form submit and update you don't need to add ajax.

**1. Option: Listener**

html:

```
<prime:spinner value="#{bean.value}" max="#{bean.hoursMaxValue}"><p:ajax Listener="#{bean.valueChangeEvent}" update="@this"/></prime:spinner>
```

bean:

```
public void valueChangeListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
   value = (double)Math.round(value*4)/4;
}
```

**2. Option: Modifiy the setter and getter**

html:

```
<prime:spinner value="#{bean.value}"><p:ajax update="@this"/></prime:spinner>
```

bean:

```
public double getValue(){
  return (double)Math.round(value*4)/4;
}

public void setValue(double value){
   this.value = (double)Math.round(value*4)/4;
}
```

**3. Option: Converter**

**Note:** You don't need to modify anything in the bean if you use a converter.

html:

```
<prime:spinner value="#{bean.value}" converter="SpinnerConverter"><p:ajax update="@this"/></prime:spinner>
```

converter:

```
@FacesConverter("SpinnerConverter")
public class SpinnerConverter implements Converter, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SpinnerConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        try {           
            Double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(value);     
            return String.valueOf((double)Math.round(doubleValue*4)/4);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ConverterException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Double getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        try {
            Double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(value);         
            return (double)Math.round(doubleValue*4)/4;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ConverterException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would personally like to see the 'rounding' in the UI too from the start even, so I'd do something in the getter to or in the `getAsString(...)` of the converter to. Then there is no need to continuously update the component via ajax.

Comment: I've updated the getter and getAsString as you recommened. It may be useful if as you said he don't want to update via ajax all the time. But I thought he may wants to see the correct value directly and not after the form submit and update. Added a note to explain it. Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: Thank you! I modified the setter and now it works! :)